# Uploaded files in WordPress not visable/useable

Tags: linux, wordpress, file, media

I have just transported my WordPress site to the server, however now that the site is uploaded I cannot use any uploaded media. By that I mean after the upload process has completed the media manager reports an error and no media can be seen. However, when I look at the directory all of the correct files are present.

Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Comment: Check the file permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be correct about the rights since files are on the server after upload. Maybe it is an issue around apache (or your webserver) path mapping.

I'm not sure, but Wordpress may use an absolute path relative to the root server directory of your wordpress site.

In Apache virtual host configuration, it looks like

```
ServerRoot  ...
DocumentRoot ...
```

In wordpress install the last line of the wp-config.php indicate

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
  define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');`
```

If it is the error, double check your url path and directory mapping (in both wordpress configuration and server configuration).
You may also have to check around database (I don't know if wordpress stored any settings about directory structure in the database).

I hope that may help you.

Regards

ollie314